# Invoking a PL/SQL package contructor

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I ran into the problem of invoking a package constructor after the package have been compiled and is in use. The problem was that with programs already using it, I could not re-compile it. Compilation seems to be one way of forcing the constructor to run again:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/packages.htm#BABEBHEG

I did not want to raise ORA-04068.

Is there any other way to do it? This is a PL/SQL package on an Oracle database, version 11g.

Update 2013/10/21: I seem so have the terminology wrong - I mean "package initializer" instead of "constructor"

Comment: What do you mean by "package constructor"? there is no such a thing in PL/SQL Packages. Would you post actual code?

Comment: @MiguelVeloso I think he talks abou Package Initializer. And yes, it runs after compilation, when the package is called for the first time. The point is: WHY you cannot recompile? Do you keep state in a Package Variable or something like that? That's a very bad idea.

Comment: Why would you need to re-compile it? Have you changed the package dynamically? Are you storing data in global types? There shouldn't be a need to re-compile a compiled object every time you call it so I would imagine there's another way. Can you describe what you are trying to achieve rather than the proposed solution.

Comment: @Y.Ecarri, Ok, Now I think I understand, I missed the ORA-04068 part, to avoid that you have to remove any package variable (declared BEFORE any procedure or function within the package), they have some quite interesting uses BTW. If you can't remove them, just re-execute the package to create a new state.

Comment: @MiguelVeloso: Me? I don't, and repeat, I DO NOT keep state in package variables :) It is WCoester

Comment: @Y.Ecarri, You're right, I'm sorry. Anyway it looks WCoester has moved on to another issue.

Comment: There are a lot of tricks around this issue... quick search for `ORA-06508`,`ORA-04065`,`ORA-04068` will give you a lot of solutions

Comment: Package initializers are run each time that the package is used in a new session. In addition, so long as the package is in use it can't be recompiled, so to just compile it successfully you'll need to disconnect all processes that are currently attached to the database and are using this package, recompile the package, and then re-start/re-attach the processes stopped or disconnected earlier. This is a good example of why processes should be designed such that long-running connections are not needed. The basic rule is "Get in, get the work done, and get out fast". Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Basically the idea is to cache some lookups at the beginning of a session. Then it would not be necessary to select them repeatedly during package invocation. The problem is that once they are in memory (or the SGA, I am not exactly sure where it is stored) you cannot update them. You can also not re-compile the package for the reasons above. So maybe this kind of optimization is not ideal in this situation.

Comment: If you want to invalidate your cache from within the session, just provide a procedure to do that. And change your getter function to check if the cache is valid (then, you don't need to use the package initialization section anymore, because you can initialize the cache upon the first call to your getter).